# MySQL, PHP: Under what situations, it's a must or advisable to use backticks?

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysqli_query($dbc, "DROP TABLE `applicants`") or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

mysqli_query($dbc, "DROP TABLE applicants") or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Form my observation, either of above two statements carries out the same operation and give the same result. So when should I quote tables and column names in SQL queries on PHP scripts? Does "quoting with backticks" highly relate to different versions of MySQL servers or PHP servers?

Comment: Not sure if they have functional value but they're usually used for field names and values.

Comment: Why are you backslash-escaping the backticks?!

Comment: @JamesPoulson I've never seen backticks used for values, only column and table names as suggested by the first answer.

Comment: good practice -> always.

Comment: Always for any column or table name. It doesn't hurt to use them, but when you don't, you'll probably get in trouble and the reason might not be easy to find

Comment: @ChrisRasco You're right. Not used to using backticks myself. I was thinking of single quotes.

Answer (score 6):

You only have to use backticks when you use column or table names that are [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL.

```
drop table `order`
```

for instance needs backticks since `order` is a reserved word.

Comment: I would add that it's good to be consistent so either decide to always use them across an application or don't. Avoiding reserved words where possible is also not a terrible idea. Table prefixes FTW

Comment: I disagree. I only use it when necessary.